# 2 Dimensional Char Array to CStrings, where each row is a separate string

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I'm reading a multi-dimensional char array from a file

```
char pszBillToAddress[3][31];
```

Each row of this array holds a line of an address, and ultimately I need to separate all of the components into separate strings for Address, City, State, and Zip, but for now getting each row into its own CString is my goal. What would be a good way to go about doing this? Use a for loop to append all the characters in a row to a CString?

Comment: is it 3 dimensional as the title says or 2 dimensional as the declaration says?

Comment: 2 dimensional, my mistake, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Why assume that all addresses fit in 3 lines?

Comment: Because that's how they're stored in the data structure I'm reading them from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0;  i < 3;  ++i)
{
    strAddress[i] = pszBillToAddress[i];
}
```

Assuming that those are truly zero terminated strings. If there's any possibility that they will be filled to the end of the array with characters and the null terminator is missing, you'll need a different approach.

Comment: This would have worked, but I discovered with a little more legwork I can read each field (Address, City, State, etc) individually from the same source that the array was populated from.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is setup, I am assuming each column is a different line of the address with a c-string of 31 characters max?

In any case, `pszBillToAddress[0]` (same for [1] and [2]) are already c-strings. If you want them in a single c-string, you could do a few things. Perhaps the easiest is to use a string `char x[93];` and use `strncat()` but this is a "C" way of doing things.

I mean something like this:

```
char pszBillToAddress[3][31];
char x[93];
*x = '\0'; /* Empty string */

/* Retrieve data here somehow */

strncat(x, pszBillToAddress[0], 31);
strncat(x, pszBillToAddress[1], 31);
strncat(x, pszBillToAddress[2], 31);
```